# How to Edit users list using `meteorJs`?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need help for i had develop the **meteorjs app** in that i want edit client row {{cid}} value  but it is not working.Here is my code please verify and where did i mistake suggest me.

```
clientJs:
//Edit client info
Template.client.events({
    'click .clientrow':function(e,t){

         console.log("You Edit Client Row");
         e.preventDefault();
        alert(tmpl.data._id);

    }
});
my template:
            <table class="table table-bordered tablestriped table-hover">
               <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Client Id</th>
                        <th>Medical RNO</th>
                        <th>Client</th>
                        <th>Referral Date</th>
                        <th>Referred By</th>
                        <th>Clinician</th>
                        <th>Service</th>
                        <th>Episode</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>                        
                    </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                {{#each clientList}}
                    <tr class="clientrow">
                        <td>{{cid}}</td>
                        <td>{{mrno}}</td>
                        <td>{{client}}</td>
                        <td>{{formatDate rdate}}</td>
                        <td>{{referredby}}</td>
                        <td>{{clinecian}}</td>
                        <td>{{serviece}}</td>
                        <td>{{episode}}</td>
                        <td>{{actions}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {{/each}}               
               </tbody>
            </table>
```

Comment: So, what is wrong? What is happening, and what is not? Please specify your question and format your code to be more readable.

Comment: alert message is not getting user name or id @Hubert OG

Comment: For beginners, `alert(tmpl.data._id);` should be `alert(t.data._id);` But what is the problem? What is not happening? What error do you get when you do what? Where's your template helper code for clientList etc...

Comment: In alert box not getting client name and details it showing unrefined on alert box @Serkan Durusoy

Comment: You're displaying `_id` in the alert, not the name nor details - what did you expect to get?

Comment: _id is also not getting it display unrefined@Hubert OG

Comment: we need this value {{cid}} in alert box.@Hubert OG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template.client.events({
    'click .clientrow':function(e,t){

```
     e.preventDefault();    
     console.log("You Select Client Row " + this.client);
         alert(this.mrno + ' ' + this.client);               

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I'm tired, so this may need some tweaking, but

var cid = $(t).find('td:first').text();

or

var cid = $('td:first', $(t).parents('tr')).text();

or

var cid = $('td:first', $(t)).text();

or